# *scratch* buffer using SLIME

Tags: emacs, lisp, slime

I realize that SLIME is the Superior Lisp Interaction Mode but I'm wondering if there is a "Lisp Interaction" buffer that works with Common Lisp like the *scratch* buffer works with Emacs Lisp.  I.E. hitting C-j at the end of a form will insert the result of that form in the current buffer.

I ask because I find editing the output as needed is easier this way than with the repl.

Answer (score 4):

There is <kbd>M-x</kbd>`slime-scratch`<kbd>RET</kbd> though I don't
know what does <kbd>C-j</kbd> by default because I use
[Paredit](http://emacswiki.org/emacs/ParEdit).

However <kbd>C-u</kbd><kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>C-e</kbd> does what you want in
both `*scratch*` and `*slime-scratch*`.

```
It is bound to C-x C-e.

(eval-last-sexp EVAL-LAST-SEXP-ARG-INTERNAL)

Evaluate sexp before point; print value in minibuffer.
Interactively, with prefix argument, print output into current buffer.
Truncates long output according to the value of the variables
`eval-expression-print-length' and `eval-expression-print-level'.
```

(and it's `slime-eval-last-expression` in the `*slime-scratch*` buffer)

Comment: I took a look for through the slime docs trying to find something like slime-scratch but couldn't.  Pretty obvious and thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Binding this function to C-j does the behaviour that I'm looking for:

```
(defun slime-eval-print-last-sexp ()
  (interactive)
  (newline)
  (insert (cadr (slime-eval `(swank:eval-and-grab-output ,(slime-last-expression)))))
  (newline))
```

Comment: `slime-eval-last-expression` already exists in `SLIME` and its
behavior is the same as `eval-last-sexp`.

Comment: slime-eval-last-expression does not return it's output and only prints it to the minibuffer. I had to hunt for the way to get the actual evaluated output and came up with the above.

Comment: Looks like this already exists with slime-eval-print-last-expression but I didn't find it and it doesn't print the final newline but it's pretty close.